# Matrix reconstruction with Rowsum, Colsum and pecentage calculation

Tags: r, matrix

I am trying to calculate the percentage of each variable from the matrix as below

```
var1  5 6 7 8  
var2 6 8 9 10  
var3 5 4 3 2
```

I want to calculate the percentage from the matrix considering first three columns in a dataframe to further use it in my plots this way

```
var1 33.9622641509  
var2 43.3962264151  
var3 22.641509434
```

For this i did this way which is not working so far

```
rowSums(p[, 1:3])*100/colSums(as.data.frame(p[, 1:3]))
```

Any help/suggestions is highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do,

```
rowSums(prop.table(m1[,1:3]))
#     var1      var2      var3 
#0.3396226 0.4339623 0.2264151
```

Or

```
rowSums(prop.table(m1[,1:3])) * 100
#    var1     var2     var3 
#33.96226 43.39623 22.64151
```

Comment: Thank you it works very well. Prop.table is good function. But i have problem further in the dataframe processing. i wanted to filter based on the column >5 using m1[which(m1$per>5),]

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean. What is `per`? You need to update your question, provide reproducible example, and expected output.

Comment: I just changed the colname. here is the code m1<-as.data.frame(rowSums(prop.table(p[,1:3])) * 100), colname(m1)<-"per"

Comment: So you mean `m1[m1$per > 5,]`? or maybe `m1[m1$per > 5, , drop = FALSE]`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I fixed it.